# Black body (Black hole) radiation

Tags: thermodynamics, black-holes, temperature, thermal-radiation, hawking-radiation

I have a question regarding Black body (black hole) radiation.

Is it correct to say that the black hole radiation is the hawking radiation? How is the formula for the wavelength of hawking radiation related to the black body mass? In Wikipedia i couldn't find anything on this.

Comment: Wien's law gives you about the peak wavelength of the spectrum of a black body of a certain temperature - that $T$ is the black body's temperature, and the wavelength is the peak of the spectrum. In other words, it's not an applicable relation at all points in an object's spectrum.

Comment: I see, so it is the peak and not the typical wavelength. But shouldn't there be a relation to the mass of the body? I mean that is what is typical of the black hole, the mass

Comment: Maybe you should read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawking_radiation and the connection with black body radiation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-body_radiation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Wikipedia:

> Hawking radiation is black-body radiation that is predicted to be released by black holes because of quantum effects near the black hole event horizon. It is named after the physicist Stephen Hawking, who developed a theoretical argument for its existence in 1974.

In the same article (to be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawking_radiation#:%7E:text=Hawking%20radiation%20is%20black%2Dbody,for%20its%20existence%20in%201974.)) you can find that this radiation corresponds to that of a black body with temperature:

[image]

The last ratio in this equation is the ratio between the mass of the sun and that of the black hole.

You can use this temperature to find the relation between the spectral radiance of the Hawking radiation:

[image]

This spectral radiance is that of an ordinary black body. So when you know the temperature $T$ of the black body to which the Hawking radiation corresponds, you can find the (black body) spectral radiance of the Hawking radiation. Obviously, when the mass of the black hole increases, the radiation will correspond to lower temperature black bodies.

> How is the formula for the wavelength of hawking radiation related to the black body mass?

For this, you just have to plug in the $T$ of the first formula into the second equation for the black body spectral radiance.